# DSP.js- Amplitude change the frequency and more

Tags: javascript, node.js, signal-processing

I am trying to understand dsp.js. I am using three packages in node-js with the following codes in the below(to generate sound, play and plot it as a picture inside node.js). In the below codes if I change the amp ( amplitude of the Sine oscillator) the frequency of the sound changes!. I also do not understand why when I reduce the frequency it looks I also have aliasing as the sound should be pure Sine wave. For example if f=10 Hz and Fs=8000 Hz.
Here are the code that I used for the testing purpose:

```
var dsp = require('digitalsignals');
const ChartjsNode = require('chartjs-node');
const Speaker = require('speaker');
const stream = require('stream');
var wave = [];
Fs=44100;
amp=1;
f=Fs/64;
buf=512;
var osc = new dsp.Oscillator(dsp.SINE, f, amp, buf, Fs);
osc.generate();
wave = osc.signal;
// Create the Speaker instance
const speaker = new Speaker({
  channels: 1,          // 1 channel
  bitDepth: 16,         // 16-bit samples
  sampleRate: Fs  
});
  let bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
  bufferStream.end(wave.toString());
  bufferStream.pipe(speaker);
var xy=[];
var c=0;
wave.map(item=>{
  xy.push({x:c/Fs,y:item});
  c++;
});

var chartNode = new ChartjsNode(1024, 350);
  data = {
  datasets:[{
    data:xy}]
  };
  var options = {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: data,
    options: {
      title:{
        display: true,
        text: "Wave"
      },
    }
  };
  chartNode.drawChart(options).then(()=>{
    return chartNode.getImageStream('image/png');
  }).then(streamResult => {
    return chartNode.writeImageToFile('image/png', './testimage.png');
});
```

The first picture shows when the amp is 1. Even though from the picture it looks a Sine wave but what you hear from the speaker is not Sine. In the second picture amp is 100 that sounds look like a noise but still it is a Sine wave with amplitude 100.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not too familiar with these packages, but I'm guessing you could create the `Speaker` with `float: true` argument, and not convert the `wave` to a string when piping it in the `bufferStream`.

Comment: Thanks but I should convert it to string or buffer as it is a stream. I also tried to use Buffer.from(wave) which in this case it returns a buffer with 0 ( no sound). Float in speaker did not effect anything for me